# Cannot find xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, screen-scraping

I want to scrape the reviews for https://www.sephora.com/product/double-wear-stay-in-place-makeup-P378284?icid2=products%20grid:p378284
But the xpath I found is not returning any value:

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="ratings-reviews"]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/text()').extract()
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not seeing any reviews on the website URL you've given. Also not seeing anything within the HTML with id="ratings-reviews". Are you sure you have the correct url ?

Comment: That XPath matches and finds content when I search in Chrome developer tools. It is likely that the comments are added to the document via progressive enhancement with JavaScript after the original HTML for that page loads, and may not be available to a scraper that does not evaluate JavaScript.

Comment: How do I scrape the JavaScript part? Do I have to use selenium?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a separate request to extract Reviews as these are not available in the page source. Try this

```
def start_requests(self):
    url = 'https://api.bazaarvoice.com/data/reviews.json?Filter=contentlocale%3Aen*&Filter=ProductId%3AP378284&Sort=SubmissionTime%3Adesc&Limit=30&Offset=0&Include=Products%2CComments&Stats=Reviews&passkey=rwbw526r2e7spptqd2qzbkp7&apiversion=5.4&Locale=en_US'
    return [Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)]

def parse(self, response):
    review = json.loads(response.text)['Results']
```

In the `review` variable you will have all the review's related fields like `ReviewText`, `Rating`

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Mads Hansen, you can't scrape this without `Javascript` support. So yes, `Selenium` or similar tool would be required here. Alternatively, you can download the `JSON` containing the reviews and extract the comments from there :

```
https://api.bazaarvoice.com/data/reviews.json?Filter=contentlocale%3Aen*&Filter=ProductId%3AP378284&Sort=SubmissionTime%3Adesc&Limit=30&Offset=0&Include=Products%2CComments&Stats=Reviews&passkey=rwbw526r2e7spptqd2qzbkp7&apiversion=5.4&Locale=en_US
```

Code  for the text reviews :

```
import requests
resp = requests.get("https://api.bazaarvoice.com/data/reviews.json?Filter=contentlocale%3Aen*&Filter=ProductId%3AP378284&Sort=SubmissionTime%3Adesc&Limit=30&Offset=0&Include=Products%2CComments&Stats=Reviews&passkey=rwbw526r2e7spptqd2qzbkp7&apiversion=5.4&Locale=en_US")
data = resp.json()

for el in data['Results']:
    print (el['ReviewText'])
```

Output :

[image: Rev]